# Why Thymeleaf templates are not found?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot 2.1.6 application (Spring 5), and I'd like to use Thymeleaf as my templating engine. I followed online tutorials to setup my project, the views and the controllers, and when I wanted to start it up I noticed that Thymeleaf complains that it is unable to find any templates:

```
2019-07-12T17:14:25,269 WARN  [main] o.s.b.a.t.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration: Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
```

I think I setup the project as it should be (at least according to the tutorials and forums I could find):

```
src/main/
    java/
        a.b.c.MyController
        rest of the classes and packages
    resources/
        static/
            css/
                bootstrap.min.css
                main.css
            js/
                bootstrap.min.js
                jquery-3.4.1.min.js
                login.js
                main.js
        templates/
            login.html
            main.html
```

My controller looks like this:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get login page", nickname = "login", notes = "", tags = { "My App", })
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success") })
@GetMapping(value = { "/", "/login" })
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
    if (error != null) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and/or password is invalid.");
    }

    if (logout != null) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");
    }

    return "login";
}
```

The login.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>My App :: Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@{/css/main.css}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My App</h1>

        <div class="container">
            <form id="userform" method="post"  action="#" th:action="@{/authenticate}" th:object="${userForm}" class="form-signin">
                <h2 class="form-heading">Log In</h2>

                <span>${message}</span>

                <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus th:field="*{username}"></input>
                </div>

                <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" th:field="*{password}"/>

                <input type="hidden" th:name="${ _csrf.parameterName }" th:value="${ _csrf.token }"/>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <script src="@{/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js}"></script>
        <script src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
        <script src="@{/js/login.js}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open the login page, I get a simple HTML page, with the word "login" written in the body.

I find this strange, Thymeleaf is looking for the templates in 'classpath:/templates/', which should be correct, because I have log4j2 XML configured in application.properties as 'logging.config=classpath:log4j2-${spring.profiles.active}.xml', and this XML is found in the same src/main/resources folder. So what can be the reason why the templates folder is not found there?

Update:

I forgot to mention: I tried to run it from Eclipse as a Spring Boot app, and also tried to run it with Maven as mvn spring-boot:run, with same results.

Also, I'm using Java 12. My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.artifactid</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <version>${baseversion}.${gitcommitcount}.${buildnumber}</version>
    <description>My App</description>

    <properties>
        <baseversion>1.0.0</baseversion>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <springfox-version>2.9.2</springfox-version>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>

        <buildnumber>0</buildnumber>
        <gitcommitcount>0</gitcommitcount>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>id</id>
            <name>Internal Local Releases</name>
            <url>http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/repository/local_release/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>id</id>
            <name>Internal Local Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/repository/local_snapshot/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>id</id>
            <url>x.x.x.x:xxxx/repository/local_group/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <!--
                    Will need to be excluded from final WAR
                    <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>*.xml</exclude>
                    -->
                </excludes>
                <includes>
                    <!-- Include is only for running locally -->
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                    <include>*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <release>12</release>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>--enable-preview</jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>false</archiveClasses>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Built-On>${maven.build.timestamp} UTC</Built-On>
                            <ModuleName>${project.name}</ModuleName>
                            <ModuleVersion>${project.version}</ModuleVersion>
                        </manifestEntries>
                        <manifestSections>
                            <manifestSection>
                                <name>Release section</name>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <BaseVersion>${baseversion}</BaseVersion>
                                    <BuildNumber>${buildnumber}</BuildNumber>
                                    <GITRevision>${gitrevision}</GITRevision>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </manifestSection>
                        </manifestSections>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>rename-wars</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>scripts/rename-wars.bat</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Commons HttpClient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Commons IO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Oracle JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CSV parsing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Javax Mail for email validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Actuator to gather metrics and health -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Update 2: application.properties

```
server.port=9080
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.jackson.date-format=a.b.c.RFC3339DateFormat
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
logging.config=classpath:log4j2-${spring.profiles.active}.xml

# Setting session timeout
server.servlet.session.timeout=10m

# ThymeLeaf settings
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

# dbcp2 settings
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-on-return=false
spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query=select 1 from dual
spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.dbcp2.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=30000
spring.datasource.dbcp2.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=30000
spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=10
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=20
spring.datasource.dbcp2.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.log-abandoned=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.log-expired-connections=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-wait-millis=1000
spring.datasource.dbcp2.remove-abandoned-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.remove-abandoned-on-maintenance=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.remove-abandoned-timeout=60
spring.datasource.dbcp2.num-tests-per-eviction-run=3
spring.datasource.dbcp2.default-auto-commit=true

# File upload settings
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1

# Actuator settings

# Actuator endpoint settings
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoint.loggers.enabled=true
management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,metrics,loggers,info
management.health.cassandra.enabled=false
management.health.couchbase.enabled=false
management.health.db.enabled=true
management.health.diskspace.enabled=true
management.health.diskspace.path=/
management.health.elasticsearch.enabled=false
management.health.influxdb.enabled=false
management.health.ldap.enabled=false
management.health.mail.enabled=false
management.health.mongo.enabled=false
management.health.neo4j.enabled=false
management.health.rabbit.enabled=false
management.health.redis.enabled=false
management.health.solr.enabled=false

# App info for actuator
info.app.name=My App
info.app.description=My App
info.app.version=1.0.0
info.customer=My App
```

Update 3: added Template and View resolvers as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class TemplateBeans implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML5")
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver servletContextTemplateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver(
                servletContext);

        servletContextTemplateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return servletContextTemplateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

        springTemplateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

        return springTemplateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf view resolver")
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

        thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return thymeleafViewResolver;
    }
}
```

With this, I get exception:

```
2019-07-15T14:43:21,382 DEBUG [http-nio-9080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.FrameworkServlet: Failed to complete request: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "/classpath:/templates/login.html")
2019-07-15T14:43:21,389 ERROR [http-nio-9080-exec-3] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/AICGDPR] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "/classpath:/templates/login.html")] with root cause
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource "/classpath:/templates/login.html" does not exist
```

I also tried with ClassLoaderTemplateResolver instead of ServletContextTemplateResolver, I got a somewhat different exception:

```
2019-07-15T14:48:54,208 DEBUG [http-nio-9080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.FrameworkServlet: Failed to complete request: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "classpath:/templates/login.html")
2019-07-15T14:48:54,217 ERROR [http-nio-9080-exec-1] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/AICGDPR] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "classpath:/templates/login.html")] with root cause
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ClassLoader resource "classpath:/templates/login.html" could not be resolved
```

Comment: Can you add your applications properties/yaml files?

Comment: Are you saying everything works fine but your are seeing Warning message ?

Comment: @want2learn No, the template is not opened, instead I only see the string "login" in the HTML body, not the "login.html" template. But I figured it's for the same reason that Thymeleaf logs that warning that the templates are not found.

Comment: Just wondering if you are using restcontroller annotation. Make sure you are using controller annotation.

Comment: @want2learn I used RestController annotation, good call, after changing to Controller, I am getting an error saying that the template cannot be resolved. So after switching the annotation, it is at least trying to resolve the template.

Comment: This is a simple case of reading the documentation. You’re using a template resolver that looks in the servlet context - ie your web directory. Yet your templates are in the class path. So what resolver might work? `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver`! (clue’s in the name). Change the resolver and remove the class path prefix. 

TBH you can probably remove quite a lot of this spurious config as most of what you have done simply overrides Spring Boot defaults in ways you don’t seem to want anyway...

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: Test with a simple template, may be the error is in it.
Look at the terminal output, may be you get another error too, like `Could not parse as expression`

Answer (score 0):

Change the location of your login page to static instead of template.
It should be as follows,

`resources/static/login.html` instead of `resources/templates/login.html`.

And don't forget to specify the extension in your controller, `return "login.html";`

(Hope you have configured view resolver, because if not your endpoint will be returning the string "login.html")

Comment: Nope, still the same. I moved the html files to the static folder, and tried with "login", and "login.html" also, stil the same. Also, I'm not sure what's the point of the template resolver, when everything is in the default location? As far as I can see, in the template resolver you can only configure the same stuff that I added to my applicaiton.properties (template location, prefix, suffix, etc).

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I read Template Resolver for some reason not View Resolver :) I added them now, please see the updated question

Comment: where is your login.html. Is it still in resources/template or did you move it resources/static

Comment: It is in resources/templates. But I tried in resources/static also (copy, not move).

Comment: I tried. I have my html files in the templates and in the static folder also. I'm returning "login.html" from my controller. I'm using ThymeleafViewResolver, but for that I need a TemplateResolver also. I tried ClassLoaderTemplateResolver, ServletContextTemplateResolver, SpringResourceTemplateResolver, all the same. Suffix is set to empty string because I return login.html, for prefix I tried "/resource/static/", "/static/", "static/", "classpath:/static/", all combinations, I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Also, I'm wondering, all tutorials say that for Spring Boot I just need to include the thymeleaf-starter dependency, and have my resources in the templates folder, and all done, no need for customer resolvers of any kind. What could I miss that I would need all this custom code to make it work?

Comment: Files typically have an extension, it can be natural to include them when returning template path in the controller. Thymeleaf automatically appends the suffix, so we should avoid supplying it.

We should place templates in src/main/resources/templates. If we want to use a different location, we need to either set the spring.thymeleaf.prefix property or create our own ClassLoaderTemplateResolver bean to handle multiple locations.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using JSP instead. Works flawlessly on first try.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as well. What I did to solve it was explicitly stating the templates path at the `application.properties` file from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/41319170/14550345 :

```
 spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true # Check that the template exists before rendering it.

 spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true # Check that the templates location exists.

 spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true # Enable MVC Thymeleaf view resolution.

 spring.thymeleaf.prefix=src/main/resources/templates/ # Prefix that gets prepended to view names when building a URL.

 spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html # Suffix that gets appended to view names when building a URL.
```

(I replaced the `classpath:` by the hardcoded path)

Comment: it doesn't help. It still gives me thmeleaft-templates-are-not-found

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue happened because the resources folder in IntelliJ was not marked as "Resources". I needed to:

> File > Project Structure > Modules > pet-clinic-web
> Click on sources tab
> src>main>java>resources
> Click on the resources folder
> Click on Mark as: Resources
> Click on Apply
> Click on OK

Answer (score -2):

hey i was suffering with same type of problem. After a long time i discovered that i was missing the class level mapping. For example i was writing this code for my case:

```
@Controller
public class ProviderController {
    @GetMapping(value = "providers")
    public String getAllProviders(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("roomReservations", null);
        return "provider";
    }
```

and thyleaf wasn't detecting my view. I solved this issue by using following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "providers")
@Controller
public class ProviderController {
@GetMapping
    public String getAllProviders(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("roomReservations", null);
        return "provider";
    }
```

i hope it will resolve your issue too.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately I may not be able to verify this anymore, maybe with a new test project. I'll try when I'll have some time.