# Java Spring Boot & Thymeleaf: An error happened during template parsing

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm developing a Java Spring Boot Web App where users can register. When they register, they get sent a verification email. This is no longer working when I've tried to get the link in the email to actually confirm the registration because I get the error: "An error happened during template parsing (template: "mail/verifyEmail.html")". I'm not sure why this could be. I've attached below the verifyEmail.html file, and then the accompanying EmailService.java file which has the EmailService() and sendVerificationEmail() methods:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<th:block xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<span th:text="'Hello ' + ${name}"></span>

<p>Thank you for registering for the bcoreHW site!</p>
<p>Please click <a href="#">here</a> to verify your email address.</p>

</th:block>

</html>
```

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

@Service
public class EmailService {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Value("${mail.enable}")
    private boolean enable;

    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    private void send(MimeMessagePreparator preparator) {
        if(enable) {
            mailSender.send(preparator);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    public EmailService(TemplateEngine templateEngine) {

        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("mail/"); 
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        this.templateEngine = templateEngine;
    }

    public void sendVerificationEmail(final String emailAddress) {

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("name", "Bob");

        final String emailContents = templateEngine.process("verifyEmail", context);

        System.out.println(emailContents);

        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

            // not working for some reason: @Override
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {

                MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);

                message.setTo(emailAddress);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no-reply@testSite.com"));
                message.setSubject("Please Verify Your Email Address");
                message.setSentDate(new Date());
                message.setText(emailContents, true);
            }
        };

        send(preparator);
    }
}
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with this? Thanks. Also, here is the error message I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ClassLoader resource "mail/verifyEmail.html" could not be resolved
    at org.thymeleaf.templateresource.ClassLoaderTemplateResource.reader(ClassLoaderTemplateResource.java:130) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
```

Comment: I am not able to recreate any error based on the info in your question. There should be a detailed error message on the server, when the Thymeleaf rendering or template parsing  fails, containing one or more "caused by..." reasons. Can you add those to the question?

Comment: Side note: It is more typical to see `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">` rather than `<th:block xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">`. In other words, the namespace is in the `<html>` tag, not in any other tag. But that does not appear to matter in this case.

Comment: Sorry about that. Posted above.

Comment: Thanks. Take a look at related questions - for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318005/how-to-locate-thymeleaf-template-from-spring-boot/41319170) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028909/spring-boot-and-thymeleaf-cant-find-html-templates) - and probably others. I think it's more typical in SpringBoot to put your Thymeleaf templates in `src/main/resources` - and then _not_ explicitly set anything via the resolver. Let Spring do its automagic. (I don't use Spring much).

Comment: I found the issue. My prefix "mail/" is incorrect because it's actually in a directory called "mailTemplates". My goodness haha.

Comment: You are always welcome to create an answer to your own question, especially if you think it will be useful to other people. You can even accept your own answer if you wish.

Comment: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ClassLoader resource "mail/verifyEmail.html" could not be resolved --> Check your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. My prefix "mail/" is incorrect because it's actually in a directory called "mailTemplates". Silly me.